# How to perform complex insert, select, update in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables - `ACCOUNTS` and `USERS`:

ACCOUNTS:

```
CREATE TABLE  `ACCOUNTS` (
  `pk` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `primary` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `edit_on` bigint(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1234567890 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

USERS:

```
CREATE TABLE  `USERS` (
  `user_id` bigint(9) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

if `edit_on` contains a non-null value, it means the entry is an edit on an existing entry, whose `pk` is contained in `edit_on`.

Here's what I want to do:

1. For every `user_id` in `ACCOUNTS`, there should be a matching `user_id` in `USERS`.
2. If `edit_on` is `not null`, there should exist an entry in `ACCOUNTS` with it's `pk` equal to this (input) `edit_on` and `user_id` equal to this (input) `user_id`. And for that (old) entry, `status` should be set to `E`.
3. If `primary = 'Y'`, then for other rows in `ACCOUNTS` with the particular `user_id`, `primary` should be set to `'N'`

After experimenting a hell lot with different queries (using `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` etc.), I still cant find a solution. Please help, as I've been working on this for 2 full days. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here's something along the lines of what i've tried so far:

```
insert into ACCOUNTS
case
    when edit_on is null
        then
            select null, '222222222', 'N', null)
    else
        select null, '222222222', 'N', pk)
        from ACCOUNTS
            where '222222222' = user_id and '2147483680' = pk
        select pk, '222222222', 'N', pk)
        on duplicate key update status='E'
end
```

I haven't done anything about `primary` yet *PLUS* this one's not the solution :D

Comment: Are you constrained to using MyISAM engine, or can you use InnoDB?  Trying to do this using case statements isn't going to work very well in a concurrent environment.

Comment: Simply switch to InnoDB and define proper foreign keys. Everything else will be a error-prone and ugly workaround.

Comment: I can use InnoDB, no probs :) But I still dont have a complete solution :(

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert as my problem is still unsolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need two constraints:

1) `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. This will ensure that any `user_id` inserted into `ACCOUNTS` exists in `USERS`.

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS
ADD FOREIGN KEY
accounts_user_user_id (user_id)
REFERENCES USERS (user_id)
```

2) Self-referencing `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. This will ensure that any value inserted into `edit_on` is a valid value from `pk` in `ACCOUNTS`.

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS
ADD FOREIGN KEY
accounts_accounts_edit_on (edit_on)
REFERENCES ACCOUNTS (pk)
```

Optionally, you can define what actions you want `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` of the referenced key. You can read more about `FOREIGN KEY` constraints [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

You need to make sure that `user_id` on both tables is of the same type, and that both tables are `InnoDB`.

Comment: Switch to InnoDB.  And for requirement 3 - either use a trigger, or a constraint on a calculated field.

Comment: @PinnyM: MySQL parses but ignores check constraints.

Comment: your point 1 is fine, but regarding 2, i also need to make sure that the `user_id` is same too. Also, what if the value of `edit_on` is null?

Comment: @eggyal, how sad.  Perhaps just switch to another DBMS then.  Just kidding, you can emulate check constraints using one of several harebrained methods.  Google is your friend.

Comment: @th3an0maly When you mean `same`, do you mean that the inserted `user_id` matches the parent `user_id`?

Comment: exactly. in short, it means that the person editing the account is the original owner

Comment: @njk Could you pls see the question again? I've edited requirement# 2 slightly, and have still not got a clue as to what to do about 3. I've defined the foreign keys

Comment: Here's a link to how the problem looks now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert