# MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Here's what I'm trying to do:

When there's a new `INSERT` into the table `ACCOUNTS`, I need to update the row in `ACCOUNTS` where `pk` = `NEW.edit_on` by setting `status='E'` to denote that the particular (old) account has been edited.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `setEditStatus`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `setEditStatus` AFTER INSERT on ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    update ACCOUNTS set status='E' where ACCOUNTS.pk = NEW.edit_on ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The requirement is **NOT** that I manipulate the *newly inserted* column, but an *already existing* column with `pk = NEW.edit_on`

However, I can't update the same table: `Can't update table ACCOUNTS ... already used by the statement that invoked this trigger`

Please suggest a workaround

PS: I have already gone through [Updating table in trigger after update on the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547465/updating-table-in-trigger-after-update-on-the-same-table), [Insert into same table trigger mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504904/insert-into-same-table-trigger-mysql), [Update with after insert trigger on same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925651/update-with-after-insert-trigger-on-same-table) and [mysql trigger with insert and update after insert on table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870465/mysql-trigger-with-insert-and-update-after-insert-on-table) but they dont seem to answer my question.

**Edit**

`ACCOUNTS` Table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `ACCOUNTS` (
  `pk` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `edit_on` bigint(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`) USING BTREE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483726 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: How do you uniquely identify the rows in `ACCOUNTS`? If `edit_on` is your primary key, then how can you insert duplicates?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the table structure. Please see.

Comment: if `edit_on = 123` for a row where `pk = 456`, that means `456` is an edit on `123`. Therefore, `status` should be updated to `'E'` for `123`

Comment: There is no `status` column in your schema.

Comment: oops.. sorry my bad. please see the edit now

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems that you can't do all this in a trigger. According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247590/mysql-trigger-set-values-for-new-row-and-update-another-in-the-same-table), it seems that you should:

> create a stored procedure, that inserts into/Updates the target table, then updates the other row(s), all in a transaction.

With a stored proc you'll manually commit the changes (insert and update). I haven't done this in MySQL, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974325/mysql-transaction-within-a-stored-procedure) looks like a good example.

Comment: Does that mean I have to call the stored procedure from the trigger?

Comment: No, I believe you move the original `INSERT` query into the stored procedure, and call the proc instead of the query. Here's the syntax for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Do you mean move the original insert into a procedure and use a trigger to make the updates, or moving the *whole* logic into a stored procedure?

Comment: Putting two statements (insert + update) in a stored procedure. If statements execute successfully, then you `commit`, otherwise `rollback` changes.

Comment: good news. I've implemented that. It works fine. Except for the fact that I cant get the status (if or not the SP changed any rows) in  my JDBC Template :(

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-last-insert-id.html

Comment: Actually i figured it out. I just had to check the return value of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update()`. Everything's fine now :) Thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: Could you post your solution to this page? How does it look like at finish?

Comment: @th3an0maly no, it will not work, I tried it, the best way as I think is calling the procedure after the update query

Answer (score 13):

This is how I update a row in the same table on insert

`activationCode` and `email` are rows in the table `USER`. 
On insert I don't specify a value for `activationCode`, it will be created on the fly by MySQL.

Change `username` with your MySQL username and `db_name` with your db name.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` 
       TRIGGER `db_name`.`user_BEFORE_INSERT` 
       BEFORE INSERT ON `user` 
       FOR EACH ROW
         BEGIN
            SET new.activationCode = MD5(new.email);
         END
```

Comment: Very nice solution!!!
The solution suggested by pjama is fine, but it didn't fit my case, while this one works great and doesn't need a stored procedure

Comment: Yes, the important thing is not to write an UPDATE ACCOUNTS part, which is what MYSQL prevents.

Comment: This got my downvote because it completely ignores the clearly stated request that the update should be acting on a DIFFERENT record, not on the newly inserted one.

Comment: Tried this and it did not work for me 

CREATE TRIGGER `add_comment_hash_after_insert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `comments` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET new.comment_hash = 'aa';
END;

Comment: Hey Nice Solution! it's simple and works just fine for me, thanks for sharing.

Comment: I know that the answer is not relevant for what is being asked, but people like me are getting the required solution from this answer in most cases even after 6 years.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem but had to update a column with the id that was about to enter, so you can make an update should be done BEFORE and AFTER not BEFORE had no id so I did this trick

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `codigo_video`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `codigo_video` BEFORE INSERT ON `videos` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE ultimo_id, proximo_id INT(11);
    SELECT id INTO ultimo_id FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
    SET proximo_id = ultimo_id+1;
    SET NEW.cassette = CONCAT(NEW.cassette, LPAD(proximo_id, 5, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have to say, this is a very crude way to solve this issue because it banks on the premise that no entry was added/deleted (thus increasing the autoincrement value from what the MAX(id) + 1 would yield).  Regardless it's the only solution I've found to accomplish what I need to and I feel like I can bank on that premise.  I'm attempting (due to moving from PHP to Django) to rename all my primary keys from TABLENAME_id to id without breaking my application.  Good stuff.

Comment: This got my downvote because it completely ignores the clearly stated request that the update should be acting on a DIFFERENT record, not on the newly inserted one.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `setEditStatus`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `setEditStatus` **BEFORE** INSERT on ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    SET NEW.STATUS = 'E';

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the last entry; this is another trick:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ... and table_name = ...
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit in an edit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use before insert and get max pkid for the particular table and then update the maximium pkid table record.