# how to create trigger to do concatenation of fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I have 1 table like this:

```
user
----------------------------------------
id | first_name | last_name | full_name
----------------------------------------
```

I want to write a trigger which will concat the first_name and last_name to full_name.

I have tried below trigger :

```
delimiter |
create trigger fullname after insert on user
for each row
begin
update user set full_name=(select concat(first_name,last_name) from user where id=new.id)where id=new.id;
end;
|
```

It's shows this error while inserting data to user table:

`#1442 - Can't update table 'user' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change a table while the INSERT trigger is firing. You can, however, create a trigger before inserting the record.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `fullname` BEFORE INSERT ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET NEW.full_name = CONCAT(NEW.first_name, ' ', NEW.last_name);
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: oops my mistake this logic of creating trigger before inserting record didn't strike in my mind....its working :)
thnk you sir...!!!

Answer (score 2):

For your case, I would like to suggest you to use computed column instead of trigger, because trigger you need to create for insert/update;

Hope this can help you.

```
    create table [users] 
    ( id int identity(1,1),
      First_Name varchar(100),
      Last_Name varchar(100),
      Full_Name as concat(First_Name,' ', Last_Name) persisted
   )
      Insert into [users]
      select 'Bob', 'Ryan'
```

```
     select * from [users]

    update users 
    set First_Name = 'Michael'
    where id=1

    select * from users
```