# Updating DATETIME with trigger, get error 1442 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1442

I am having trouble with a trigger in MySQL. I have a column named "last_modified" that I want to be automatically updated with the current date and time when it is the table is edited. Using a trigger, this is my SQL query:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_responders BEFORE UPDATE ON survey_responders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE survey_responders
SET NEW.last_modified = CURRENT_DATETIME();
END;//
```

However, when I update the table, such as with this query:

```
UPDATE survey_responders SET first_name = "bob" WHERE id = "1";
```

MySQL Workbench displays error 1442: "Can't update table 'table_name' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger"

I have looked at similar questions with the same error but still have not fixed it. Help is appreciated.

** UPDATE **

This did the trick:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_responders BEFORE UPDATE ON survey_responders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.last_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END;//
```

Seems like I simply did not need to repeat the

```
UPDATE survey_responders
```

and CURRENT_DATETIME() did not exist, I had to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

Comment: Any reason for not updating last_modified column in update statement itself?

Comment: This is part of an assignment; it requires me to use a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_responders BEFORE UPDATE ON survey_responders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.last_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END;//
```

Seems like I simply did not need to repeat the

```
UPDATE survey_responders
```

and CURRENT_DATETIME() did not exist, I had to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible using a trigger.

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

You need to do this some other way.

See here: [MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert)

> The typical way to do that, is to create a stored procedure, that
>   inserts into/Updates the target table, then updates the other row(s),
>   all in a transaction.