# MySQL trigger to UPDATE entire table before INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a trigger that updates a particular attribute for all the tuples of a table, before a new tuple is inserted.

So whenever I run `INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (...);` I want the salary of all previously stored employees to be decreased by 300, that is, `UPDATE Employee SET Salary = Salary - 300;`

I'm really new to SQL so I naively tried the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER reducesalary BEFORE INSERT ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Employee SET Salary = Salary - 300;
```

Of course, I then found out this is incorrect since triggers cannot work on the same table that calls them. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why would you reduce the salary automatically if a new employee is added?

Comment: It's not a practical thing, but just suppose there is a real-world condition that requires reduction in everyone's salary whenever a new employee is hired.

Comment: @juergend because all the employees pay for the new guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been already asked here,

[MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert)

You need to use stored procedures