# Need an idea to reinsert a row in a table with same primary key values using trigger in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'm having a table with 3 columns say a,b,c where a is the primary key. Consider it has a value

> 1 hai hello

Using triggers i need to insert another row value as

> 1 bye hello

please note that i want to insert the value not to update and i want to perform this in trigger.

First i have planned to do it with trigger in BEFORE INSERT, but I'm getting an error while inserting the value.

> Error: Can't update table 'table1' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

I'm already having another trigger in AFTER INSERT.

Comment: AFAIK you [can't target the same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert) in a trigger, and MySql doesn't have INSTEAD OF triggers which would allow you to duplicate the record. IMO you are doing too much in the triggers - as per the link, recommend you create a procedure and insert both records through this.