# Create trigger to update one column value when update or insert happens in the table

Tags: mysql

I have created table  by following

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
`MyTable_ID`  int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
CreationDate  datetime NULL , 
UpdateDate`  datetime NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`MyTable_ID`)
);
```

Here I have 2 columns `CreationDate` and `UpdateDate`.

I want to write only one trigger for both update  and insert operation to update/ insert CreationDate, UpdateDate columns.

If I am doing

1. insert operation I want to update CreationDate,UpdateDate columns
2. if I am doing update operation I want to update only UpdateDate.

Thank you.

Comment: Create two triggers.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert