# mysql trigger to update one field of the newly added row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 'users' table with the following fields:-
user_id (int, auto increment PK)
encrypted_userid (varchar 50)
user_name (varchar 50)
user_location (varchar 50)

What I want to do is create a trigger so that when values are inserted into the users table into user_name and user_location, i want to populate the encrypted_userid field with an AES_ENCRYPTED value from user_id - e.g. AES_ENCRYPT(user_id,'MYAESKEY') but only for the newly INSERTed row

Is this possible in MySQL with some kind of trigger?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any need to create trigger?

Comment: you can insert AES_ENCRYPTED value while inserting row.

Comment: I need to try and do it this way, as the number of pages in the three websites that insert currently into the users table would take forever to change, so I thought using a trigger may be easier, as the encrypted_userid is going to be a new field, so I can update the new field against existing user_id values but for future entries once the new field goes live i need to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So is there a solution to my problem that will not fail etc? using a trigger - all other solutions i tried from reading other sources just didn't work.*

Well all solutions revolve around [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) because it's **the only** multi-user safe way to obtain auto generated ID.

---

**First** possible way, if you're very fond of triggers, is to have a separate table for auto generated sequences. Your schema will look like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_seq (user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT);
CREATE TABLE users
(
  user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 1, 
  encrypted_userid varchar(50), 
  user_name varchar(50), 
  user_location varchar(50),
  FOREIGN KEY user_id_fk (user_id) REFERENCES users_seq (user_id)
);
```

And the trigger

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER useridinserttrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO users_seq() VALUES();
  SET NEW.user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(),
      NEW.encrypted_userid = AES_ENCRYPT(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'MYAESKEY');
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Second** way is to leverage your existing schema but use a stored procedure

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user(IN _name VARCHAR(50), IN _location VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE _id INT;

  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_location) VALUES(_name, _location);
  SET _id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  UPDATE users 
     SET encrypted_userid = AES_ENCRYPT(_id, 'MYAESKEY')
   WHERE user_id = _id;
  COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```sql
CALL insert_user('johndoe', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using [MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert) (JCLG's entry)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `useridinserttrigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `users` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE tmpid,tmpid2 INT(11);
    SELECT user_id INTO tmpid FROM users ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1;     
    SET tmpid2=tmpid+1;
    SET new.encrypted_userid=AES_ENCRYPT(tmpid2,'MYAESKEY'); 

END;
```

Comment: I hope you're aware that this solution will fail miserably under load. More over in your case it will fail silently by grabbing improper id and producing corrupted value.

Comment: So is there a solution to my problem that will not fail etc?  using a trigger - all other solutions i tried from reading other sources just didn't work.