# MySQL Trigger Not Functioning

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created this Trigger. However, when inserting into dbase, nothing happens?

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `collectionsmax`$$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `DupeCheck` AFTER INSERT ON `dbase` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        update dbase set reportfilenumber=socialsecruitynumber where id = new.id;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute DML statements against the table your trigger is written against.  This is a caveat in most databases.

See [MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert).  The accepted answer has a different way of approaching the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work in my situation. A 3rd party application is making the INSERT into my DB, and I need to actively run this Trigger when this happens.