# Create trigger to update the table row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hi there i would like to create a trigger for (It's **MYSQL**)

what i had first, which doetn't work correct, keep getting project_id to 0 and hash value and insert the **project_id_md5**.

```
CREATE TRIGGER project_auto_md5 BEFORE INSERT ON project 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.project_id_md5 = md5(NEW.project_id);
```

then i have changed to after, this time the **project_id_md5** field become empty.

```
CREATE TRIGGER project_auto_md5 AFETER INSERT ON project 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE project SET project_id_md5 = md5(project_id);
```

Please help out the problem any help is great appreciated.

Comment: What SQL Server are you using? SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: MYSQL is the one. sorry i will update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert#12878145

Comment: @HowardWang so trigger can't do it basically?