# Recursive Trigger in mysql update the id child where include parent's id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I want make after update trigger in MySQL database, 
I have a `user` table, `user` table is self join. I want make trigger when `id` in `user` is update will update at another table `req_konfirmasi` and table `nikah`. but I want update with another `id` in `user` table

ex :

```
|id  |name
|01  |a
|011 |b
|012 |c
```

so `b` is child from `a` because `b` have contain `id` from `a`, and if `id` from `a` is update so `id` from `b` will update too,

```
UPDATE user SET id = 03 WHERE id=01
```

so i will get new data in table like this

```
|id  |name
|03  |a
|031 |b
|032 |b
```

and I want update with trigger in MySQL, and my trigger is like this

```
Delimiter //
    CREATE TRIGGER update_id_user AFTER UPDATE ON user
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN    
        SELECT RIGHT(id,2) id_child from user where id like 'OLD.id%'
        IF count(id_child) >= 0  THEN
            UPDATE user SET id = CONCAT(NEW.id,id_child) WHERE id like 'OLD.id%'
        END IF;
    END;
End Delimiter //
```

but it's just update in `req_konfirmasi` and `nikah` table. the childs id is not update, please help me for my problem

Comment: similar with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert

Comment: thanks's but i want make a rekursif update for childs more than one

Comment: anyone can help me, for thatproblem?