# trigger after update to delete row on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

i want to create trigger after update to delete row on specific condition
i did find similar question here but the code won't work with me.

This is what i try to do :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER delete_rejected_friendship
AFTER UPDATE
    ON friendship FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF Update(RequestState)
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM friendship WHERE RequestState = 'reject'
        END
   END
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the error which appears:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Update(RequestState)
>         Begin
>              DELETE FROM friendship WHERE Reque' at line 9`

so i have friendship table that have three columns userID , friendID and RequestState. this table represent friendship relationship and friendship request state. if RequestState= accept then they are friends and if RequestState = reject the row should be deleted.

Edit :
if update(requeststate) for if the column = requeststate updated (changed from 'waiting' state to either 'accept' or 'reject' state) then the other condition in delete statement (WHERE RequestState = 'reject') to specify only change to 'reject' state

Comment: What is that condition if update(requeststate)

Comment: I don't think you can do this, q.v. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert).  Perhaps you can rework your logic?

Comment: Please give more explanation about the condition If Update(RequestState)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please do not correct casing, what if the error comes from there? Not that SQL is case sensitive, but anyhow, excepting indentation or empty lines, we should keep the original code when editing.

Comment: @Cristik I'm aware of this type of problem.  I was only trying to make the problem more readable so other SO users can help.

Comment: @sagi I edit the question to add more explanation

Comment: @shukri gashi I edit the question to add more explanation

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thank you for the correctness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, You are using `Update(RequestState)` condition like `PostgreSQL`, in `MySQL` or `MariaDB` could be like that:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER delete_rejected_friendship
AFTER UPDATE
    ON friendship FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.RequestState <> OLD.RequestState THEN
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM friendship WHERE RequestState = 'reject';
            END;
        END IF;
   END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: it's give me error (unexpected character ,(near ;) in delete statement line and END IF line. and if i delete the semecolon from these two line it will give me this error (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END
        END IF
   END
END' at line 8) @Carlos Rodriguez

Comment: @showihd Sorry, I edit the answer, delete the last `END` and add the `END;`, I run this query on mysql console and run fine, but, in Navicat gave me an error but, create the trigger fine, so verify when you run this query.

Comment: thank you, the trigger created now. but when i run my update query to test the trigger it will give me this error :(#1442 - Can't update table 'friendship' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger) and this is the update query i tried: (UPDATE friendship SET RequestState = 'reject' WHERE UserID = 1 AND FriendID = 4;)

Comment: This need a revision from you part, because you can do delete when `RequestState='reject'`, so no need update for set `RequestState='reject'`, yo need delete in this instance, because, you execute the update, the update wait because this execute a trigger, this wait because this execute a delete...

Comment: Thank you very much Carlos ! your answer really helpful. I solve the problem with SQL statement, i don't know why my brain immediately think of trigger when there is easier way!. thank you again.

Comment: @showihd no problem, you can mark my answer as the correct answer? Thanks.