# Create SQL trigger to update row value

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have a SQL table "Inbox" with column "modem_id" and "user"
I would like to create a SQL trigger when the modem_id is 1, the "user" column is being inserted value 'A'; 2 for user 'B'...

I have created a SQL trigger with if else:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_user_inbox BEFORE insert ON inbox
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF NEW.modem_id = 0 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'A' WHERE modem_id = 1; 
         ELSEIF NEW.modem_id = 2 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'B' WHERE modem_id = 2; 
            ELSEIF NEW.modem_id = 3 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'C' WHERE modem_id = 3; 
            ELSEIF NEW.modem_id = 4 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'D' WHERE modem_id = 4; 
            ELSEIF NEW.modem_id = 5 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'E' WHERE modem_id = 5; 
            ELSEIF NEW.modem_id = 6 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'F' WHERE modem_id = 6; 
            ELSEIF NEW.modem_id = 7 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'G' WHERE modem_id = 7; 
            ELSEIF NEW.modem_id = 8 THEN
             UPDATE `inbox` SET `user` = 'H' WHERE modem_id = 8; 
         END IF;
     END;//
delimiter ;
```

The trigger execute successfully but it is not working.
If 'if-else' does not work, anyone could teach me using 'case' instead?

Thank you

Comment: You can't modify a table in a trigger which was invoked by modifying the same table, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert).

Comment: You might be able to handle this by writing a stored procedure.

Comment: Do you want to set the user column in the current row you are inserting to 'A' , 'B' etc? If so, don't use an update,  just set the `NEW.user = 'A'`  etc.

Comment: @RyanVincent yeah it works by using :

IF NEW.modem_id = 1 THEN
             SET NEW.user = 'A';

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

```
CASE NEW.modem_id
WHEN 0 THEN ...
WHEN 2 THEN ...
...
END CASE
```