# ¿because I can not update a table associated with a triggers on mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I am programming a trigger (in workbench 8) for mysql that is triggered after an insert to the table, my trigger is as follows:

```
 DELIMITER //
Drop trigger if exists tr_pago;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_pago after insert on pago for each row 
BEGIN
    declare ultimoidpago int;
    declare idcompromisopago int;
    declare idunidadrecaudadora int;
    declare idboleta int;

    Set ultimoidpago = new.IdPago
    Set idcompromisopago  = (select new.CP_IdCompromisoPago from pago where IdPago = ultimoidpago);
    Set idunidadrecaudadora = (select UR_IdUnidadRecaudadora from compromiso_pago where IdCompromisoPago = idcompromisopago);
    Set idboleta = (select IdBoleta from boleta where UR_IdUnidadRecaudadora = idunidadrecaudadora );
    update pago set new.B_IdBoleta = idboleta where IdPago = ultimoidpago;
END
DELIMITER //
```

But when making an insert to the payment table, I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'pago' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert)

Answer (score 0):

This is a MySQL restriction in a trigger. Within a trigger, it is not allowed to issue a DML statement (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) against any table that is referenced in the statement that caused the trigger to be fired.

Looks like we are wanting to set a column in the inserted row to a value.

This would typically be better handled in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. A `BEFORE INSERT` trigger is allowed to perform `SELECT` on other tables.

```
SET NEW.B_IdBoleta = expr ;
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

It's not clear what we are intending this trigger to do. But we know it can't issue an `UPDATE` on `pago`.

Here's an example of a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that attempts to set the value of the `b_idboleta` column from the result of a query. We add a continue handler to catch the error if the SELECT query doesn't return a row.

```
 DELIMITER //

 CREATE TRIGGER tr_pago
 BEFORE INSERT ON pago
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1329 BEGIN SET NEW.b_idboleta = NULL; END;
    SELECT bo.idboleta
      INTO NEW.b_idboleta
      FROM compromiso_pago cp
      JOIN boleta bo
        ON bo.ur_idunidadrecaudadora = cp.ur_idunidadrecaudadora
     WHERE cp.idcompromisopago = NEW.cp_idcompromisopago
     ORDER
        BY bo.idboleta
     LIMIT 1;
 END//

 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: try to perform the update with before and I have the same problem

Comment: @PabloMoraga: Do NOT perform an UPDATE.  Just SET the value of the column being inserted, using the special `NEW.` qualifier.