# SQL: counting rows refering to tables own id

Tags: mysql

I have a table set up like this (simplified for this example)

```
ID            | int  |Primary auto increment
Name          | text |
ContainerID   | int  |
ContainsCount | int  |
```

I am using the container id to refer to the table itself. So if i have a row with

```
ID:3 Name:Test1 ContainerID:0 ContainsCount:0
ID:4 Name:Test2 ContainerID:3 ContainsCount:0
ID:5 Name:Test3 ContainerID:3 ContainsCount:0
```

It means that the row 4 and 5 is inside row 3.

I would like to count how many row are inside row 3, and store it in the ContainsCount column.
I know i can get this value manually by doing an additional query for every row that i need to read. But i would like to avoid the strain on the server.

I have tried setting up a trigger that increments the value every time a new row with the corresponding id is added

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE Stock_Items Set Name = "Testing" Where ID = 2;
END
```

But it turns out i cannot edit the same table using a trigger.

Is there any other way to achive this?

Comment: do check this answer (if haven't done so): https://stackoverflow.com/a/12878145/2469308