# MYSQL How can I update a row in a table after updating the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Each row of my table has a child, For example ID 1 is parent of 11 and 11 is parent of 111 and each row has a balance, I need that if I update the balance of 111, the balance of 11 update and the balance of 1 too

for example: `UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET value = 100 WHERE ID = 1`
In this case the value of 11 is going to be 100 and the value of 1
then I can do  something like this : `UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET value = value + 150 WHERE ID = 11;` in this case The value of 11 is going to be 250 and the value of 1 will be 250 and the value of 1 should stay 100. I need to do something like that

IM using mySQL

Comment: what problem are you facing in using update statements ?

Comment: I need something like a trigger for automatically update the parent rows but Update the same table in a trigger is not allowed by myql

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert)

Comment: I did but didn´t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, MySQL will generally not allow you to define an update trigger which itself would trigger more updates on the same table.  One option here, assuming you are using MySQL 8+, would be to define a recursive CTE which targets all records intended for the update:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, value, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, value, parent_id
    FROM ACCOUNTS
    WHERE id = 111
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t1.parent_id
    FROM ACCOUNTS t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
)

UPDATE ACCOUNTS a1
INNER JOIN cte a2
    ON a1.id = a2.id
SET value = 100;
```

This assumes that you would want to do the same update logic for each matching `id` in the hierarchy.  The CTE will generate all records starting from `id = 111`, and working backwards up the tree to the root.

Comment: Have some doubs, Can you apply that to my table?

The table structure is

```CREATE TABLE `cuentascontables` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 
  `balance` int(255) NOT NULL,


  `PARENT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;```

Comment: @OmarAlmonte Sorry for the late reply, but it appears you already figured out that the CTE isn't part of the table definition, it is part of the update code that you would run.

Comment: Its ok, can you APPLY CTE to my table please? I mean the same code but using my column names Thanks in advance

Comment: Again, the CTE should be executed before, and along with, the update statement.  A CTE makes no structural changes to your actual code.

Comment: I mean, can you apply CTE with my column names? sorry for bad explanation

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that, because you never told us the column names.