# How to update a table field using after insert trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to update inserted row field name is "hash_code" with MD5().

```
DELIMITER
    //
CREATE TRIGGER `make_hash2` AFTER  INSERT ON
    `newtable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        _id INTEGER ;
    SELECT
        id
    INTO _id
FROM
    `newtable`
ORDER BY `id`
DESC
LIMIT 1;

 

UPDATE
    `newtable`
SET
    `hash_code` = MD5(_id)
WHERE
    id = _id ;
END
```

**I tried using the following code but throwing the following error on insert.**

#1442 - Can't update table 'newtable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: I don't think you can do everything with the trigger. maybe try with Stored Procedure. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877732/mysql-trigger-for-updating-same-table-after-insert)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `hash_code` to be the `md5()` hash of the id, you can use a generated column:

```
alter table newtable add column hash_code varchar(32) as
     (md5(id))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=813401f424f5909187e375cf32caad94) is a db<>fiddle.